# Can't understand why this output is produced

Tags: c, math, operators

```
main()
{
    int a = 10, b = 5, c = 5;
    int d;
    d = a == (b + c);
    printf("%d", d);
}
```

OUTPUT:  1

Can anyone please explain how this value is assigned to d??

Comment: `1` = true. It's parsed as `d = (a == (b + c))`. d gets the result of the boolean comparison you're doing.

Comment: `a == (b + c)` evaluates to true or false. And since `d` is `in`, truth value of `true` is 1. Hence the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`==` has a higher precedence than `=`, so

```
d = a == (b + c);
```

is equivalent to:

```
d = (a == (b + c));
```

it tests if `a` is equal to `b + c`, `1` if true, and `0` if false.

Answer (score 2):

`a == (b + c)` is true, true is represented by a 1 from your compiler, that's why d becomes 1.

if the sum of `b + c` was not equal to 10 it would have printed 0

Remmeber in C false is represented by 0, any other value means true.

Thus

```
if(-1)
{
    printf("true");
}
```

prints true

Answer (score 1):

`==` returns 1 if its operands are equal and 0 if they're not.